# Is the boy girl paradox relevant in this here?

Tags: probability

I have a hard time understanding this probability example. Suppose behind a door, there is either X, Y or Z.

Your told:
The probability of X being behind the door is 50%.
The probability of Y being behind the door is 25%.
The probability of Z being behind the door is 25%.

Someone goes and opens the door and tells you that Z is not behind the door. What is the probability that Y is behind the door with this new information?

How would one answer this question? And how would you even begin to tackle it?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan that comes out to be $33.3\%$

Comment: @PhilH absolutely! I am so sorry, I was thinking one thing and typing the other. My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After it is revealed that $Z$ is not behind the door, the ratio of  probability of $X$ being behind the door to the probability of $Y$ being behind the door does not change. Originally we have $\frac{P(X)}{P(Y)} = 2$, so now we have $P(X) = \frac{2}{3}$ and $P(Y) = \frac{1}{3}$, since the probabilities must sum to $1$.